# Hide "no internet" notification on Android

Tags: android, notifications, wifi

I'm preparing application for Android which uses external devices connected by WiFi.
These devices have no access to Internet. Android system always show notification that WiFi have no access to Internet. Is it possible to hide these notifications.

Maybe it will help -- I'm connecting to these devices programmatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an os level notification there is nothing you can do about it.